# Regex Crossword missing 4th capture group

Tags: regex

On [BrainF*ing](https://regexcrossword.com/playerpuzzles/f365a038-23b7-4727-8842-388424001edd) regex crossword I'm looking at the fourth row `((([<+>])\3\3)|(<-])(?=>))+`. I already worked on the fifth column `\++\-+\.+\-+\++` and I believe `-` ends up on the fourth row.

What I have so far: `<<< ->>  +++` (spaces here are unknown). It seems to me that the `-` is out of place/can't belong (unless the first and last space is `[<\-\]]`). Looking at it with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lU9iK4/3) I plugged in `<<<-->>>]+++` (just for testing and it doesn't see `--` or `]`, also on the right side the fourth capture group isn't listed. Is there a reason regex101 doesn't see the fourth capture group: `(<-])`? Am I right in that `-` is a valid possibility?

Comment: Sorry, but your input string has no `<-]` substring. How come you expect to match what is not in the string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what do you mean my input has no `<-]` substring?

Comment: `(<-])` matches a `<-]` substring. Your `<<<-->>>]+++
+++-.--+
->
<>
]>
` does not contain this substring.

Comment: oh...wow.....ty, I was thinking `[<\-\]]` for some reason

Comment: Does it mean you need https://regex101.com/r/lU9iK4/4?

Comment: no, I misunderstood the regex, it should be like: https://regex101.com/r/lU9iK4/5

Comment: I do not think it makes sense to wrap the `<-]` inside a capturing group - it will be inside a repeated group, and only the last value captured will be kept. [`(?:([<+>])\1\1|<-](?=>))+`](https://regex101.com/r/lU9iK4/6) must be enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146082/discussion-between-depperm-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(<-])` part is a *capturing group* that matches a sequence of atoms, here, a  `<-]` 3-char substring.

To match any symbol, `<`, or `-` or `]`, these symbols should be put them into a character class, `[<\-\]]`.

Note that your string contains no `<-]` substring, so `<-]` won't match. Once you added it, your regex will work.

It usually not necessary to use capturing groups inside a repeated group, as in most languages only the last value captured is kept in the match object (PyPi Python regex module and .NET regex engines keep them all).

So, you might use

```
(?:([<+>])\1\1|<-](?=>))+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU9iK4/6)

**Details**:

- `(?:([<+>])\1\1|<-](?=>))+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `([<+>])\1\1` - a `<`, `+` or `>` followed with exactly the same char 2 times
- `|` - or
- `<-](?=>)` a `<-]` substring that had `>` after it (without consuming `>`, it is free to be used by the next match iteration since it is inside a positive lookahead).